# Trying to change output for a timer in a form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, timer

I need to make a form in C# have a timer and have a label that will have be the  display of the timer. The label will need to be a generic label at first saying it is a counter, but when the timer starts it needs to display the count. Currently I have the display as  a number up down but, it needs to be the control that can tweak the count, which it does. It just can't be the sole counter.

Here is my assignment:

Create a Windows Application. In the main form, create a label named “lTickCount”.
Create a timer named “tPeriodic”, and a numerical control of your own choosing.
**Each time the timer “ticks” increment an integer, display the integer value as a string in
lTickCount.** Use the numerical control to change the update rate of the timer
interactively.

I think I have done everything correctly except for the bold part. To finish I tried to make a string in both the label and the counter. I know I shouldn't have in both, I just wanted to show you the two things I've tried to help get better feedback:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA ########";
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                TickCounter.Text = "The timer has started";
                tPeriodic.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TickCounter.Text = "The timer has ended";
                tPeriodic.Enabled = false;
            }

        }

        private void TickCounter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TickCounter.Text = TickCounter.Value.ToString();
        }

        private void tPeriodic_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TickCounter.Value += 1;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TickCounter.Text = TickCounter.Value.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right way?

Comment: what is TickCounter?

Comment: Also if you read your question closely the numeric updown counter is supposed to be used to change the update frequency(interval) of your timer, not modify the output

Comment: Valter - TickCounter is my number up down tool. Mark Hall, I was wondering if I was reading the problem right. What is the frequency? Changing the number while the program is running?

Comment: Most likely your timer is firing every 100ms that is the default you can change the frequency by setting the timer's interval property like this. tPeriodic.Interval = (int)TickCounter.Value;

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to try to add to a string (A label value) you need to convert it to an Integer first.

A couple ways to do this:

```
TextCount.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextCount.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

is one way, of course you could still use your += or any other math syntax for basic addition of +1.

You can also use tryParse, and in fact this should probably be used to verify you have an integer in the first place:

```
   int count;
   if (int.TryParse(TextCount.Text, out count))
        {
            count++;
            TextCount.Text = count.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Hey Austin, It needs to be the same label as the lTickCount which already exists. I think the teacher wants the label to change to display the count and the number up down needs to adjust the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count;
int tmrInterval = 1000; //1 sec
private void tPeriodic_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    lTickCount.Text = count.ToString();
}

private void TickCounter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TickCounter.Value == 0)
    {
        return; // or stop the timer
    }
    tPeriodic.Interval = TickCounter.Value * tmrInterval;
}
```

*tPeriodic.Interval* is the time till next tick in milliseconds.
You are updating the timer interval according to *tmrInterval* and the value of the numeric control.  You can change the interval or the formula i wrote to your own.

valter

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found that:

tPeriodic.Interval = 1000 / Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value);

seemed to work in the numericupdown class.

Thanks for the help.